# Show $f^*dx_i = \sum_{j=1}^l \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j} dy_j = df_i$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-topology

Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology Page 164:

$U \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and $V \subset \mathbb{R}^l$ be open subsets. Let $f: V \to U$ to smooth. Use $x_1, \dots, x_k$ for the standard coordinate functions on $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $y_1, \dots, y_l$ on $\mathbb{R}^l$. Write $f = (f_1, \dots, f_k)$, each $f_i$ being a smooth function on $V$. The derivative $df_y$ at point $y \in V$ is represented by the matrix $$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}(y),$$
and its transpose map $df_y^*$ is represented by the transpose matrix. **Consequently,**

> $$f^*dx_i  = \sum_{j=1}^l \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j} dy_j = df_i.$$

---

**My solution:**

For a smooth function $f$, $df$ is linear. And $df^*$ is the adjoint of the map $df_*$.

Consider a tangent vector $Y \in T_yU$ such that
$$Y = \sum_{j = 1}^l Y^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}.$$

Then we have
$$(f^*dx_i)(Y) = (f^*dx_i)\sum_{j = 1}^l Y^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}.$$

[$f^*$ is linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457403/linearity-of-f-f), $dx_i$ is linear, and the composition of linear function is linear. Hence $f^*dx_i$ is linear. So
$$(f^*dx_i)\left(Y^1\frac{\partial}{\partial y^1} + \cdots + Y^l\frac{\partial}{\partial y^l}\right) = (f^*dx_i)\left(Y^1\frac{\partial}{\partial y^1}\right) + \cdots + (f^*dx_i)\left(Y^l\frac{\partial}{\partial y^l}\right).$$

By [Commutativity of $Y^j$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461237/commutativity-of-yj/461287?noredirect=1#461287):
$$ Y^1(f^*dx_i)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^1}\right) + \cdots + Y^l(f^*dx_i)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^l}\right) = \sum_{j=1}^l Y^j (f^*dx_i)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\right).$$

Use the definition $$f^*\omega = \omega \circ f_*.$$

We have
$$\sum_{j=1}^l Y^j (f^*dx_i)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}) = \sum_{j=1}^l Y^j dx_i(f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j})).$$

Because $f$ maps from $V \subset \mathbb{R}^l$ to  $U \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, it can be written as
$$f = (f_1, f_2, . . . f_k),$$
with each $f_i$ being a function of the $y_j \in V \subset \mathbb{R}^l$. Consider and $g:U \to R$ sufficiently differentiable, then the vector field $f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j})$ on $U$ may be applied to $g$:

$$f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j})[g(x_1, x_2, . . . x_k)] = \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}(g(f_1(y_1, . . . y_l), f_2(y_1, . . . y_l), . . . f_k(y_1, y_2, . . . , y_l))),$$
according to the definition
$$(F_*X)(f) = X(f \circ F).$$

Hence,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}(g(f_1(y_1, . . . y_l), f_2(y_1, . . . y_l), . . . f_k(y_1, y_2, . . . , y_l))) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}(g(x_1, \dots, x_k)).$$

Following Chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}(g(x_1, \dots, x_k)) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^1} \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^j} + \cdots + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^k} \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial y^j} = \sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n} \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j}.$$

That is
$$f_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\right)[g(x_1, x_2, . . . x_k)] = \sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n} \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j}.$$

By commutativity of first-order derivative,
$$\sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n} \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j} =
\sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n} .$$

Thus we see that the vector field $f_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\right)$ satisfies
$$f_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\right) =  \sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}.$$

So
$$\sum_{j = 1}^lY^jdx_i(f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j})) = \sum_{j = 1}^lY^jdx_i\left(\sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\right).$$

As before, we use the fact that $dx_i$ is linear, and first-order derivative is commutative,
$$\sum_{j = 1}^lY^jdx_i\left(\sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\right) 
= \sum_{j = 1}^lY^j\left(\sum_{n = 1}^k dx_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j}\right).$$

Using $dx_i(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}) = \delta_{in}$,
$$\sum_{j = 1}^lY^j\left(\sum_{n = 1}^k dx_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j}\right) 
= \sum_{j = 1}^lY^j\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}\right)
= \sum_{j = 1}^l (dy_j Y)\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}\right).$$

So,
$$\sum_{j = 1}^l (dy_j Y)\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}\right)
=\sum_{j = 1}^l\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}\right) (dy_j Y).$$

According to [Show that $d\phi = \sum \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i}dx_i.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455156/d-phi-sum-frac-partial-phi-partial-x-idx-i) We have
$$df = \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}dy_i.$$

So
$$\sum_{j = 1}^l\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}\right) (dy_j Y)
=df_i (Y).$$

Since this holds for any $Y \in T_yV$, we have shown that
$$f^*dx_i = \sum_{j = 1}^l \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}dy_j = df_i$$

Comment: No, no, no. $dx_i$ is $dx_1$ if $i=1$, $dx_2$ if $i=2$, and so on. But what exactly are you asking, anyway?

Comment: Hi @BranimirĆaćić - I am asking how to prove the identity in the title. And I showed my thoughts that won't work.

Comment: Yes, @RSalimi :)

Comment: Your notation is inconsistent. You cannot have at the same time a $df_x$ and a $df_i$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd like to point out, before trying to answer this question, that your definitions confuse me a little.  For instance, what is $I(y)$?  And in your expression for $\omega$,

$\omega = \sum_{1 \le i_1 < . . . i_k \le n}I(y)dx_i$,

why is there apparently a multi-index of some sort on the $\Sigma$ symbol which doesn't seem (to me at least) to occur in the summand $I(y)dx_i$?  Well, perhaps this stuff is explained in Guillemin and Pollack, which I haven't looked at in quite awhile, fine book though it be.  Not trying to be critical here, merely seeking clarification.

Having said these things, let's try to prove that

$f^*dx_i = \sum_{j = 1}^l\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}dy_j = df_i$.

I'm going to try to do this the way I learned it, mostly from general principles; as I indicated above, I don't have a copy of Guillemin and Pollack in front of me, so if I seem like I'm winging it, bear with me . . .

The first thing you need to know is that $f^*$ is the adjoint of the map $f_*$, in the sense usually used in linear algebra:  if $T:V \to W$ is a linear map between vector spaces $V$ and $W$, then for any $\sigma \in W^*$ we define the linear functional $T^*\sigma \in V^*$ by the formula $T^*\sigma(v) = \sigma(Tv)$ for vectors $v \in V$.  Thus it is easily seen that $T^*:W^* \to V^*$ is also a linear map.  This idea of course applies pointwise with respect to $U$ and $V$, i.e. fiberwise with respect to the tangent and cotangent spaces of $U$ and $V$.  Now let's look at $f^*dx_i$.  For any tangent vector
$Y \in T_yU$, we have

$(f^*dx_i)(Y) = dx_i(f_*(Y))$,

and with

$Y = \sum_{j = 1}^l Y^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$

we obtain

$(f^*dx_i)(Y) = (f^*dx_i)(\sum_{j = 1}^l Y^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j})$,

and by linearity of everything this yields

$(f^*dx_i)(Y) = \sum_{j = 1}^lY^j (f^*dx_i)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}) =  \sum_{j = 1}^lY^jdx_i(f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}))$.

We scrutinize $f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j})$.  With $f = (f_1, f_2, . . . f_k)$, with each $f_p$, $1 \le p \le k$ being a function of the $y_q$, $1 \le q \le l$, and $g:U \to R$ and sufficiently differentiable, the vector field $f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j})$ on $U$ may be applied to $g$:

$f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j})[g(x_1, x_2, . . . x_k)] = \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}(g(f_1(y_1, . . . y_l), f_2(y_1, . . . y_l), . . . f_k(y_1, y_2, . . . , y_l)))$

$= \sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n} \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j}$,

this last equality following from the fact that $x_p = f_p(y_1, y_2, . . . , y_l)$ and the chain rule.  Thus we see that the vector field $f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j})$ satisfies

$f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}) =  \sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} $,

and if this is inserted into our previous expression for $(f^*dx_i)(Y)$,

$(f^*dx_i)(Y) = \sum_{j = 1}^lY^jdx_i(f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}))$,

it follows that

$(f^*dx_i)(Y) = \sum_{j = 1}^l \sum_{n = 1}^k Y^j dx_i(\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n})$,

and using $dx_i(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}) = \delta_{in}$,

$(f^*dx_i)(Y) = \sum_{j = 1}^l Y^j \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j} =  \sum_{j = 1}^l \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}dy_j(Y) = df_i(Y)$,

since we have $Y = \sum_{j = 1}^l Y^l \frac{\partial}{\partial y_l}$ and $dy_j(Y) = Y^j$.  Since this holds for any $Y \in T_yV$, we have shown that

$f^*dx_i = \sum_{j = 1}^l \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}dy_j = df_i$,

as per request.  QED.

Whew!  Too many indices and subscripts to keep track of!

Now, as I recall, establishing this formula on $1-$forms allows it to be extended in the usual manner to all of $\Lambda(T*U)$, i.e., all form (fields) by careful use of the definitions of the $\wedge$ product and a lot of maneuvering of matrices and indices.

Gotta run, my night job beckons.

Comment: May I ask for details about how can I prove "linearity of everything" for the following step?

$(f^*dx_i)(Y) = \sum_{j = 1}^lY^j (f^*dx_i)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}) =  \sum_{j = 1}^lY^jdx_i(f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}))$.

Comment: Thanks so much Robert. I will read it very, very carefully. I think I made a mistake here because I mixed $dx_i$ with $dx_I$. So, there shouldn't be a summation.

Comment: @WishingFish: I still don't know what $I$, maybe you could enlighten me? As for the question in your other comment, the equation right above the phrase "linearity of everything" just uses the expansion of $Y$ in terms of the basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial ∂y_j}$, right? It's just straightforward substitution of $Y = \sum Y^j \frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}$.  The first equality in the equation right after the phrase "l.o.e." follows from the fact that both $f^*$ and $dx_i$ are linear maps, hence so is their composition $f^*dx_i$.  GOTO NEXT COMMENT!

Comment: The second equality in that equation follows from the abstract definition of adjoint as given in the third paragraph of the answer.  Does this help?  I accept that $f_*$ is understood to be linear.  All else follows from this--well, almost all else.  After establishing linearity abstractly, it merely remains to derive the coordinate expressions.  But I *think* I explained that in the remaining text of the answer.  If it's still unclear, leave a comment and I'll try to get back to you.  Thanks so much for the kind words.  Cheers, Robert AKA "Bob" Lewis.

Comment: Dear Bob, $I$ intended to mean $dx_I = dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_p}$.

Comment: The book defined $I$ to be strictly increasing index sequence $I = (i_1, \dots, i_p)$.

Comment: Thanks for the def. of $I$.  Thought it was something like that.

Comment: Hi Bob, I've been wondering if there is a short cut? >_<

Comment: @WishingFish:  What did you mean by a "short cut"?

Comment: Oh, because the author simply said "consequently", and gives the result. My your exposition seems very extended, so I have been wondering if this is what the author intended.. :-)

Comment: @WishingFish:  I think part of the reason for the length of my post is that I tried to go through many of the steps, even the smaller ones, in some detail for the sake of clarity.  The essential content could probably be expressed in a two- or three-liner.  So, from that point of view, I know of no "short cut".

Comment: Dear Bob, I have a very quick question on your notation
$$Y = \sum_{j=1}^n Y^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}.$$
Is it the same as
$$Y = (Y^1\frac{\partial}{\partial y^1}, \cdots, Y^n\frac{\partial}{\partial y^n})?$$
I am wondering if you would be willing to take a look? The link for the question is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460609/notation-on-the-tangent-space

Comment: Here $Y^i$s are just scalar, right? $$Y = \sum_{j = 1}^l Y^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$$

Comment: Consider a tangent vector $Y \in T_yU$ such that
$$Y = \sum_{j = 1}^l Y^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}.$$

And it should be $Y \in T_yV$..? :-) Thanks so much for your patience!!

Comment: Hi Robert, may I ask how to show
$$ (f^*dx_i)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}) =  dx_i(f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}))$$
at
$(f^*dx_i)(Y) = \sum_{j = 1}^lY^j (f^*dx_i)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}) =  \sum_{j = 1}^lY^jdx_i(f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}))$? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We know $f^*dx_i$ is tensor field and compute it at $p\in V$ which is arbitary,$(f^*{dx_i})_p$=${dx_i}_{f(p)}{f_*}_p$(from definition of pullback),also we have ${f_*}_p=df_p=\Big[\frac{\partial f_t}{\partial y_j}(p)\Big]_{k\times l},$ and ${dx_i}_{f(p)}={{x_i}_*}_{f(p)}=[0,...,0,1,0,...,0]_{1\times k}$(with 1 in ith place),the multiplication of two matrices is $\Big[\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}(p)\Big]_{1\times l}$ which is equal to ${df_i}_p$,and ${df_i}_p=\sum_{j=1}^l \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}(p){ dy_j}_p$.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think both answers offered thus far are excellent in their own way. I will merely attempt to say the same with a slightly different notation.

First, $f=(f^1, \dots, f^k)$ is a function of $y = (y^1, \dots , y^l)$. Therefore, we differentiate $f$ with respect to $y$ at the point $y=p$ we have: 
$$ df_p(h) = \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l[f'(p)]_{ij}h_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{f(p)} \qquad \text{where} \ [f'(p)]_{ij} = \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial y^j} $$
where $f'(p) \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times l}$ and $[h_j] \in \mathbb{R}^l$ thus $f'(p)[h] \in \mathbb{R}^k$. I suppose, to be explicit, $h = \sum_{j=1}^l h_j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\bigg|_p$. Here I, as is my custom, assume $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$, that is, euclidean space is made of column vectors. I'll place $dx^j$ at $f(p)$ but I'll forego adorning $dx^j$ with that point-dependence for brevity in what follows. The pull-back of $dx^j$ from the range of $f$ will form (pun-intended) a one-form $\alpha$ in the domain at $p$. We can calculate such a one-form by calculating its components in the $\{dy^1, \dots , dy^l \}$ basis for $T^*V_p$ by evaluation at the coordinate vector fields to which these are dual. Consider, 
$$ \bigl((f^*)_{p}(dx^m)\bigr)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^n}\bigg|_p) = dx^m ( df_p(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^n}\bigg|_p)) \qquad \star$$ 
Now, $h_j = \delta_{jn}$ for the coordinate vector field ($h = \sum_{j=1}^{l}\delta_{jn}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^n}\bigg|_p)$ hence
$$ df_p(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^n}\bigg|_p)) =
\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l[f'(p)]_{ij}\delta_{jn}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{f(p)} = 
\sum_{i=1}^k[f'(p)]_{in}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{f(p)} $$
Finally, feed this into the $\star$ equation,
\begin{align} \bigl((f^*)_{p}(dx^m)\bigr)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^n}\bigg|_p) &= dx^m (\sum_{i=1}^k[f'(p)]_{in}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{f(p)}) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k[f'(p)]_{in} dx^m (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{f(p)}) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k[f'(p)]_{in}\delta_{im} \\
&= [f'(p)]_{mn}
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$ (f^*)_{p}(dx^m) = \sum_{n=1}^l [f'(p)]_{mn} dy^n = \sum_{n=1}^l \frac{\partial f^m}{\partial y^n}dy^n = df^m$$

Comment: Thanks a lot James. First a quick question: why you evaluate at $f(p)$ rather than $p$?$$ df_p(h) = \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l[f'(p)]_{ij}h_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{f(p)} \qquad \text{where} \ [f'(p)]_{ij} = \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial y^j} $$

Comment: And also, should $$ h = \sum_{j=1}^lh_j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}?$$ Thank yoU~

Comment: @WishingFish I should have written $(f^*(dx^m))_p$ rather than $(f^*)_p(dx^m)$. The pull-back of $dx^m$ at $f(p)$ is a form at $p$. For the second comment, that depends on which $h$ you are asking about. I first use it as a general vector then later in my answer I identify a particular vector $\partial/\partial y^j |_p$ as $h$. Aren't you going to ask me where the transpose is?

Comment: Hi James, I haven't reach the transpose yet... I am asking where $h$ appears for the first time, as I mentioned in my first comment to your answer.

Comment: And... I am sorry, but I didn't get your explanation to my first question. Could you give me more details....

Comment: @WishingFish this ($df_p(h)= \dots $) is the definition of the push-forward written in derivation language. $df_p$ outputs vectors in the range of $f$ at $f(p)$ which happens to have basis $\partial/\partial x^i |_{f(p)}$ given the notation of this problem. My previous comment is just nit-picking the notation I used for pull-back later.

Comment: Oh... I had some idea now. Let me continue digesting your answer.. Thanks~

Comment: For the second question, I was talking about the $h$ in $$ df_p(h) = \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l[f'(p)]_{ij}h_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{f(p)} \qquad \text{where} \ [f'(p)]_{ij} = \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial y^j}.$$
Should it be 
$$df_p(h) = \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l[f'(p)]_{ij}h_j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}\bigg|_{f(p)}?$$

Comment: @WishingFish no. That would be a tangent in the domain and $|_{f(p)}$ doesn't make sense for $\partial/\partial y^i$ since those are derivations of functions on $V$.

Comment: Oh right, $f$ maps from $y_i$ to $x_i$..

Comment: Hi James, by any chance do you know why $$(f^*dx_i)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j} =  dx_i f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j})$$
at Robert's proof:
$(f^*dx_i)(Y) = \sum_{j = 1}^lY^j (f^*dx_i)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}) =  \sum_{j = 1}^lY^jdx_i(f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}))$?

Comment: @WishingFish that is the definition of pull-back of $dx^i$ under $f$, it amounts to composition with the push-forward $f_*$ or $df$ as I tend to write it... you know this :)

Comment: That's comforting to know. I almost got despair because this isn't the definition given to me. Thanks James, you are the best.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9977/discussion-between-wishingfish-and-james-s-cook)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9990/discussion-between-wishingfish-and-james-s-cook)