# Linearity of everything

Tags: differential-topology

May I ask for details about how can I prove "linearity of everything" for the following step?

$(f^*dx_i)(Y) = \sum_{j = 1}^lY^j (f^*dx_i)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}) =  \sum_{j = 1}^lY^jdx_i(f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my comments to my answer to [this question, clearly the one to which you refer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456586/fdx-i-sum-j-1l-frac-partial-f-i-partial-y-j-dy-j-df-i/456810#456810).
Feel free to leave comments if you need more info.  Cheers, RKL.