# Linearity of $f_*, f^*$.

Tags: differential-topology

The definition of $f^*$ is given to me as below. But what is $f_*$? How can I justify $f_*, f^*$ is linear?

> **Definition.** If $f: X \to Y$ is a smooth map and $\omega$ is a $p$-form on $Y$, define a $p$-form $f^*\omega$ on $X$ as follows: $$f^*\omega(x) = (df_x)^*\omega[f(x)].$$

Comment: Without more data it is anybody's guess what in the world you're talking about...maps between (co)-homology groups determined by a continuous map between topological spaces? Maps determiend on fundamental groups...?

Comment: I assumed by $f_*$ you meant pushforward, I think it is just the directional derivative. Hope you can get more authoritative affirmation.

Comment: Your question is meaningless without a more complete description.

Comment: Sorry @RyanBudney, I meant pushforward and pushback.

Comment: Push forward and pull-back of what?  And linear with respect to what structure?

Comment: oh... push forward and pull-back of smooth manifolds. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I'm asking what objects you're pushing forward and pulling back.  If you're pushing forward *manifolds* then there is no linear structure at all.  I suspect you want to push forward tangent vectors, and $f$ is a smooth map of manifolds but from your language it sounds like you do not want to do that.

Comment: Yes, I want to push forward tangent vectors, and $f$ is a smooth map of manifolds...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The construction of lower star**

For any tangent vector $v_a \in \mathbb{R}_a^n$, we can define a map $\tilde{v}_a: C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}$  by taking the directional derivative in the direction $v$ at $a$:
$$\tilde{v}_af = D_vf(a)=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0}f(a+tv).$$

The operation is linear and satisfies the product rule:
$$\tilde{v}_a(fg) = f(a)\tilde{v}_a(g)+g(a)\tilde{v}_a(f).$$

A linear map $X: C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}$ is called a derivation at $a$ if it satisfies the following product rule:
$$X(fg) = f(p)X_g + g(p)X_f$$
for all smooth function $f,g$ on $M$.
If $N$ is smooth manifolds and $F: M \to N$ is a smooth map, for each $p \in M$ we define a map $F_*: T_pM \to T_{F(p)}N$, called the push-forward associated with $F$, by
$$(F_*X)(f) = X(f \circ F).$$

---

**The linearity of $f_*$**

Consider linear maps $X, Y: C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}$, and scalar $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

\begin{align}
F_*(\alpha X + Y)(f) & =  (\alpha X + Y)(f \circ F)\\
 & =  \alpha X (f \circ F) + Y (f \circ F)\\
 & =  \alpha (X (f \circ F)) + Y (f \circ F)\\
 & =  \alpha (F_*X)(f) + (F_*Y)(f)\\
\end{align}

---

**The linearity of $f^*$**

Suppose $A: V \to W$ is a linear map. Then the transpose map $A^*: W^* \to V^*$ extends to the exterior algebras, $A^*: \Lambda^p(W^*) \to \Lambda^p(V^*)$ for all $p>0$. If $T \in \Lambda^p(W^*)$, just define $A^* T \in \Lambda^p(V^*)$ by
$$A^*T(v_1, \dots, v_p) = T(Av_1, \dots, Av_p)$$
for all vectors $v_1, \dots, v_p \in V$.

So following your definition, 
$$f^*\omega(x) = (df_x)^*\omega[f(x)]$$

Here we denote $x = (x_1, \cdots, x_p)$, where
$x_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is the $x^1$ coordinate derivation.

Hence
$$(df_x)^*\omega[f(x)] = \omega(df_x x_1, \cdots, df_x x_p).$$

To show the linearity of $f^*$, we want to show
$$f^*\omega(x + ay) = f^*\omega(x) + af^*\omega(y).$$

So we have
$$f^*\omega(x + ay) = \omega(df_x (x_1 + ay_1), \cdots, df_x(x_p + ay_p)).$$
By linearity of $df_x$, we got

$$\omega(df_x (x_1 + ay_1), \cdots, df_x(x_p + ay_p)) = \omega(df_x x_1 + a (df_x)y_1, \cdots, df_xx_p + a(df_x)y_p)$$

$p$-forms are defined to be alternating $p$-tensors, which is multi-linear. Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\omega(df_x x_1 + a (df_x)y_1, \cdots, df_xx_p + a(df_x)y_p)\\
& = &\omega(df_x x_1, \cdots, df_x x_p) + a \omega((df_x)y_1, \cdots, (df_x)y_p)\\
& = &  f^*\omega(x) + af^*\omega(y).
\end{eqnarray*}