# First part of the proof that $F^*d\beta=dF^*\beta$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

Where has the $dy^j$ gone in the highlighted equation?

I would have thought the highlighted equation should be $\displaystyle (F^*dg)(x) = \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(x)\frac{\partial g}{\partial y^j}(F(x))dy^j dx^i$

[image]

Comment: The formula at the bottom of your post kind of answers this.  I'm not sure why you think $dy^j$ should stay.  Notice that you have too many $j$ indexed variables for Einstein summation.  The $\beta_j$ are $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y^j}$ here

Comment: take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456586/fdx-i-sum-j-1l-frac-partial-f-i-partial-y-j-dy-j-df-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. For a one-form $P_sdx^s$ we have the two-form 
$$dP=\frac{\partial P_s}{\partial y^t}dy^t\wedge dx^s.$$
Note that there are two sum indexes.